# how to create pagination in php with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a pagination for PHP where the it is using the jQuery POST. I have found several links which supports the traditional way of doing it but I could not find anything with the Dynamic values.

Comment: Are the traditional way of doing it make use of Limits?

Comment: [Refer](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html) this and [this](http://onlinewebapplication.com/pagination-jquery-php-ajax-mysql/). Hope it might help you.

Comment: http://demos.9lessons.info/pagination.php

Comment: Clarify dynamic value...